# Animating HTML element from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am stuck with a code that I am trying on since a day.
The code is to change text after 1s of an HTML element.
And I am stuck in adding animation to the changing text.

```
<h1>Your Favorite Source of<span id="changingtext"></h1>
```

I am targeting the #changingtext element from jQuery.

```
(function () {
var texts = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var count = 0, interval = 1000;
addText();

function addText() {

    var usrtxt = $("#changingtext");
    usrtxt.animate({marginTop:-10}, "fast");
    usrtxt.animate({marginTop:0}, "fast");
    usrtxt.animate({marginTop:-5}, "fast");
    usrtxt.animate({marginTop:0}, "fast");
    usrtxt.text(texts[count]);
    count += count < 3 ? 1 : -3;

    setTimeout(addText, interval);

}}());
```

I want the text to animate a Bounce effect everytime it changes.
I also tried using animate.css but was not able to add class to this.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you code is right?

The tag span is not closed.

You code it `<h1>Your Favorite Source of<span id="changingtext"></h1>`

The rigth one should be `<h1>Your Favorite Source of<span id="changingtext"></span></h1>`

If the code is right in you source file, you can try method like this. It is HTML DOM.

```
HTMLElement.innerHTML="New text!";
```

Comment: Yes. The code is working fine. The text is changing every 1s.
The default jQuery animation works if I change code like this
`usrtxt.text(texts[count]).slideUp().slideDown();`

Comment: But i want to use custom animation or the "animated bounce" class of Animated.css

Comment: Here is a plugin that using custom text animation. http://sideroad.secret.jp/plugins/jQueryTextAnimation/